# Linq to Entities nested subqueries

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am fairly new to linq and am having a problem translating the following sql to linq:

```
select 
    c3.COURSE, c3.DESCR
from 
    (select c.courseprefix, MAX(c.coursesuffix) [coursesuffix]
    from 
        (select distinct SUBSTRING(course,1,3)[courseprefix], RIGHT(course, LEN(course) - 3) [coursesuffix]
        from PsCourses where LEN(course) >= 3 ) c
    group by c.courseprefix 
    ) c2 inner join PsCourses c3 on (c2.courseprefix + c2.coursesuffix) = c3.COURSE
where
    c3.COURSE_STATUS = 'A'
order by
    c3.course
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to translate this into a linq query. I am not looking for assistance on the SQL itself, just want to take the sql and do it with Linq to entities.

Comment: that is what you've been asked, what part of this sql query you don't know how to translate?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to do multiple nested subqueries. I am hoping that someone can provide me with the above sql translated into linq. I know my answer is getting repetitive, and I am not trying to be rude or anything like that but this is what I am looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use http://www.sqltolinq.com/downloads
or you can make a IQueryable, but in my personal criteria the complex queries I prefer to write in native sql

Comment: Thank you. Ultimately I was hoping to conquer this particular query in Linq, but for the sake of time I went ahead and just used a stored procedure.